# Pedir al usuario que ingrese un número mientras lo introducido no sea un entero (ciclo while)

Tags: python, python-3.x, validación

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
while True:        
    numero= int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))                                      
    if (type(numero) != int()):                                                    
        continue
    elif(type(numero) == int()):
        print("es un numero")
```

Lo que quisiera conseguir es que si el `type` de `numero` no es un entero, pase al `continue`, para que vuelva a pedir un número, y si el `type` de `numero` es entero, imprima que es un número.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error en la lógica, al hacer el casting a `int` en `numero = int(input(....))`, la variable **`numero` siempre va hacer referencia a un entero** si la cadena ingresada representa algo que puede convertirse a `int`, **o se generará una excepción (`ValueError`)** al intentar el casting sobre una cadena que no puede ser convertida a `int`, con lo que tu programa terminará. Por lo tanto no tiene sentido comprobar el tipo de `numero`.

Tienes varias opciones (como usar expresiones regulares), pero lo más simple  es que manejes la excepción:

```
while True:
    try:  # Intentamos el casting de la cadena ingresada
        numero = int(input("Ingrese un número: "))
    except ValueError:  # Si el casting no es posible iteramos de nuevo
        continue
    else:  # Si el casting fue posible imprimimos y salimos del ciclo
        print("Es un número")
        break
```

Esto validará cualquier cadena que represente un entero con o sin signo. Dependiendo de que quieras validar como "número" puede que sea conveniente el casting a `complex` en vez de a `int` o `float` si quieres incluir la posibilidad de ingresar números complejos además de floats y enteros:

```
numero = complex(input("Ingrese un número: "))
```

Lo cual por ejemplo valida también `"13+4j"`

Si quisieras validar que la cadena solo contenga dígitos (no es lo mismo que comprobar si es un entero ya que no validará el signo) se podría usar `str.isdigit`:

```
numero = input("Ingrese un número: ")
if numero.isdigit():
    ....
```

> **Nota:** aunque en este caso no procede, para comprobar el "tipo" de una variable se puede usar `isinstance` que además valida instancias de clases derivadas, p.e `if isistance(numero, int): ...`

Answer (score 2):

Hay algunos problemas en tu código. Vamos por partes.

Ten en cuenta que `int` y `int()` no son lo mismo. La primera es una clase y la segunda retorna una instancia de esa clase (es decir, un número):

```
>>> int
<class 'int'>
>>> int()
0
```

Por lo tanto la comparación correcta debería ser:

```
>>> numero = 10
>>> type(numero) == int
True
```

Pero si lo comparas con la instancia de la clase `int` (que como has visto retorna por defecto el valor 0), entonces no serán iguales:

```
>>> numero = 10
>>> type(numero) == int()
False
```

El otro problema es esto:

```
numero = int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
```

Siempre que escribas un número desde la consola obtendrás un entero ya que estás usando `int()` para convertir una cadena de texto a un entero:

```
>>> int('10')
10
```

Siguiendo la lógica de tu código (con la corrección del primer punto):

```
while True:        
    numero = int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))                                      
    if (type(numero) != int):                                                    
        continue
    elif(type(numero) == int):
        print("es un numero")
```

Por lo tanto, siempre se irá hacia el `elif`.

El otro problema es que tu código está sujeto a errores porque puedes escribir, por ejemplo, un texto como `xxxx` (yo sé que no quieres sabotear tu propio programa pero tienes que tratar de hacerlo a prueba de fallos):

```
>>> int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
Ingrese un numero: xxxxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'xxxxx'
```

Por lo tanto, tienes que capturar la excepción para esos casos:

```
while True:
    try:        
        numero = int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
        print("es un numero")
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Entonces, si se levanta la excepción, quiere decir que no es un número válido:

```
Ingrese un numero: 10
es un numero
Ingrese un numero: 20
es un numero
Ingrese un numero: xxxxx
Ingrese un numero: dasdasd
Ingrese un numero: 40
es un numero
Ingrese un numero: 50
es un numero
```